# Wordpress - How to check if the menu links are top level?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm editing post-template.php in Wordpress. The `function start_el` echoes the menu. Here I want to check if the page is a top level page so I can add a new class called "top" only to the top level pages li. **How do I check if the page/link is a top level one or not?** I need only this as I can do the rest.

I've tried with

```
if ($page->post_parent) { do_something(); }
```

but it doesn't work...

(I've already changed in the same class with success the classes' names `current_page_item and current_page_ancestor, current_page_parent` to `current` since I use a custom jquery menu that uses this class.)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if you want to add class to the top level pages with jQuery then do something

```
$('ul#main-menu>li').addClass('top_level');
```

here is ul#main-menu is your menu ul id